# Can't post using http multipart request in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying 3 long days to post the data into the api. But failed to achieve success. I am using flutter http package for that. First I tried with normal application/json  but failed. Then I tried formdata still failed. Then I came up with a idea of using multipart request. Then I try this code:

```
 Future<bool> createDisplay(String name, String category, String templateName,
      String productId) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        "https://digital-display.betafore.com/api/v1/digital-display/displays/");
    var token = localStorage.getItem('access');
    try {
var request = http.MultipartRequest("post", url);

      request.headers.addAll({
        "Authorization":
            "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjY3NDk0NTAwLCJpYXQiOjE2Njc0MDgxMDAsImp0aSI6ImY5NzRjODE4MThiMTQ2NjBiNmIzNmNmZDcwNWU1MDlhIiwiaWQiOjV9.fXHnaYDn5FT7NLzMTPPQE6HwIrMBF6HhpF1c8VHevAU"
      });

      request.fields["name"] = json.encode(name);
      request.fields["category"] = json.encode(category);
      request.fields["template_name"] = json.encode(templateName);
      request.fields["products"] = json.encode(productId);

      var response = await request.send();
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        
        return true;
      } else {
        Future.error("Error");
        return false;
      }
     
    } catch (exception) {
      Future.error(exception);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Here is my frontend code:

```
import 'package:digitaldisplay/controllers/DisplayController.dart';
import 'package:digitaldisplay/views/widgets/Display.dart';
import 'package:digitaldisplay/views/widgets/ProductDisplayCard.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class CreateDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateDisplay({super.key});

  static const routeName = "/create-display";

  @override
  State<CreateDisplay> createState() => _CreateDisplayState();
}

class _CreateDisplayState extends State<CreateDisplay> {
  String _name = "";
  String _category = "";
  String _templateName = "";
  // late int productId;
  String productId = "";
  // String catelogImage = "";
  // String video = "";
  //String productId = "";

  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  DisplayController displayController = DisplayController();

  void _addDisplay() async {
    var isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }
    _form.currentState!.save();
    bool create = await Provider.of<DisplayController>(context, listen: false)
        .createDisplay(_name, _category, _templateName, productId);
    if (create) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Created"),
              actions: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text("Return"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          });
    } else {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Failed to create display!"),
              actions: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text("Return"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ButtonStyle buttonStyle1 = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFc3232a),
      shape: const StadiumBorder(),
      minimumSize: const Size(100, 50),
    );
    final ButtonStyle buttonStyle2 = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFc3232a),
      shape: const StadiumBorder(),
      minimumSize: const Size(100, 50),
    );
    final ButtonStyle buttonStyle3 = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF111111),
      shape: const StadiumBorder(),
      minimumSize: const Size(100, 50),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF111111),
        title: const Text(
          "Digital Display Generator",
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 350,
                    width: 1600,
                    child: GridView.count(
                      crossAxisCount: 1,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      children: List.generate(6, (i) => const DisplayCard()),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                    width: 1600,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Categories",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                  width: 1600,
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text("Delete"),
                          style: buttonStyle2,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 2,
                  width: 1600,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ],
            ),

            const SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 40,
                  width: 1600,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: const [
                      Text(
                        "https://www.123123123123.com/watch-display-1212",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              height: 45,
            ),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  // alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 2,
                  width: 1600,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              height: 45,
            ),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                height: 180,
                width: 1600,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                    boxShadow: const [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                        blurRadius: 1,
                        spreadRadius: 1,
                      )
                    ]),
                child: Form(
                  key: _form,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Flexible(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                validator: (v) {
                                  if (v!.isEmpty) {
                                    return "Please Enter a valid name";
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  _name = value as String;
                                },
                                autofocus: true,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: 'Name',
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 14.0, bottom: 6.0, top: 8.0),
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 73, 57, 55)),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide:
                                        const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                validator: (v) {
                                  if (v!.isEmpty) {
                                    return "Please enter valid category title";
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  _category = value as String;
                                },
                                autofocus: true,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: 'Category',
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 14.0, bottom: 6.0, top: 8.0),
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 73, 57, 55)),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide:
                                        const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                validator: (v) {
                                  if (v!.isEmpty) {
                                    return "Please enter valid template name";
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  _templateName = value as String;
                                },
                                autofocus: true,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: 'Template Name',
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 14.0, bottom: 6.0, top: 8.0),
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 73, 57, 55)),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide:
                                        const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                // keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                validator: (v) {
                                  if (v!.isEmpty) {
                                    return "Please enter valid product Id";
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  // _product = int.tryParse(value!)!;
                                  productId = value as String;
                                },
                                autofocus: true,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: 'Product Id',
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 14.0, bottom: 6.0, top: 8.0),
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 73, 57, 55)),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide:
                                        const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Flexible(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  _addDisplay();
                                },
                                child: Text("Add Display"),
                                style: buttonStyle2,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                    width: 1600,
                    child: const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "DIGITAL FLYER",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 1600,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        Image.network(
                          "https://binaries.templates.cdn.office.net/support/templates/en-us/lt16412134_quantized.png",
                          height: 280,
                          width: 500,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: Container(
                                width: 900,
                                child: TextField(
                                  autofocus: true,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black),
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    hintText: 'Banner Text',
                                    filled: true,
                                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 14.0, bottom: 6.0, top: 8.0),
                                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                          color:
                                              Color.fromARGB(255, 73, 57, 55)),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                    ),
                                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide:
                                          const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: Container(
                                width: 500,
                                child: TextField(
                                  autofocus: true,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black),
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    hintText: 'Banner Text',
                                    filled: true,
                                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 14.0, bottom: 6.0, top: 8.0),
                                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                          color:
                                              Color.fromARGB(255, 73, 57, 55)),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                    ),
                                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide:
                                          const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                child: Text("Add Text"),
                                style: buttonStyle3,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            // Row(
            //   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            //   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            //   children: [
            //     Container(
            //         width: 1600,
            //         child: const Padding(
            //           padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            //           child: ProductDisplayCard(),
            //         )),
            //   ],
            // ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("Dashboard"),
                    style: buttonStyle1,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("Create Product"),
                    style: buttonStyle2,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("Logout"),
                    style: buttonStyle2,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here you can see a function addDisplay(). When I pass data using TextFormField and send data to the api it return with created status. But When I check the database I saw nothing at all. I mean no data inserted actually.

Edit:

I am receiving 200 status. But not saving the data in the api.

Comment: Your client code looks alright. Do you have access to the API and can you trace your request? My guess is, that the API does not handle the request correctly, or that your request does not match the API spec. Can you share some information about the endpoint you address?

Comment: If you got a 200 response it means the server said it was successful. If it actually wasn't successful it means the server is broken.

Comment: Here is an endpoint https://digital-display.betafore.com/api/v1/digital-display/displays/ here you will need authorization bearer. I am providing it. here it is:- eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjY3NTQ0MTU5LCJpYXQiOjE2Njc0NTc3NTksImp0aSI6ImY2Mjk4MjM5ZWM0ZTQzY2VhMTRkYjFlZDliMTgxZTY4IiwiaWQiOjV9.S9N23F0Qrh5aa7qJdzSAPX__0zIU-swlwBVb5ZZkM6s @TimBrückner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Flutter DIo package. After using Dio package it will be saved. Try this code:

```
  Future<bool> addDisplay11(String name, String category, String templateName,
      String catalogsImage, String catalogsVideo, int productId) async {
    try {
      Dio dio = new Dio();
      FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
        "name": name,
        "category": category,
        "template_name": templateName,
        "catalogs[0]image": catalogsImage,
        "catalogs[0]video": catalogsVideo,
        "products[0]": productId
      });
      // dio.options.headers["Authorization"] =
      //     "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjY3NTQ0MTU5LCJpYXQiOjE2Njc0NTc3NTksImp0aSI6ImY2Mjk4MjM5ZWM0ZTQzY2VhMTRkYjFlZDliMTgxZTY4IiwiaWQiOjV9.S9N23F0Qrh5aa7qJdzSAPX__0zIU-swlwBVb5ZZkM6s";
      var response = await Dio().post(url,
          data: formData,
          options: Options(headers: {
            "Authorization":
                "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjY3NTQ0MTU5LCJpYXQiOjE2Njc0NTc3NTksImp0aSI6ImY2Mjk4MjM5ZWM0ZTQzY2VhMTRkYjFlZDliMTgxZTY4IiwiaWQiOjV9.S9N23F0Qrh5aa7qJdzSAPX__0zIU-swlwBVb5ZZkM6s"
          }));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.data);
        notifyListeners();
        return true;
      } else {
        print("ERROR VAI ERROR");
        return false;
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return false;
    }
  }
```